# zsh: permission denied: /Users/ryanshumway/.ssh

Tags: github, ssh, terminal, gitlab

New to programming, and my employer had setup my SSH with Gitlab for me.
Now that I'm learning more programming I thought, hey, I'll setup another SSH for my personal projects in Github.. and then I think it replaced my gitlab SSH, and now I'm not sure how to replace my GitHub ssh and my personal one, and I'm not able to get into the configure file and see anything.

I'm at the point where I can't modify either of them and I can't do anything (personal and work).

[image: console]

**How do I get around this permission denied? It seems like there's no way to edit my config file or even see which keys are active**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check:

- your current account: id -a
- the rights associated with the ssh folder:

  ```
    ls -alrth /User/ryanshumway
  ```

Make sure you are not using your terminal as root or any other account than ryanshumway